# Get data value from an sub array using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

Good morning!
I have a bug, thanks for your help in advance.

I have array from Vuejs object form and I want to save the value of each specific key.
Let's try to loop the object then pass the key, I have error

"Trying to get property 'user_name' of non-object", exception: "ErrorException",…}

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvCqJ.jpg)

```
    array:2 [
  0 => array:2 [
    "user_name" => 6
    "user_profil" => 3
  ]
  1 => array:2 [
    "user_name" => 4
    "user_profil" => 4
  ]
]
    $team = $request->team;
   foreach ($team as $data) {
        return response($data->user_name);
      }
```

Comment: Do you really want to use `return` in the loop?

Comment: Sorry, it's $data